# .NET Class Hierarchy Poster?

Tags: .net

I remember seeing a poster a few years back that had a nice break down of the .NET framework class Hierarchy in a poster.  Every link I find to it on google points to a non-existant place on the MSDN site.. Does anyone know where one can find an up to date one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does this help? http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2008/01/12/net-framework-3-5-namespace-poster-updated.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Is this what your looking for

http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/a/3/4a3c7c55-84ab-4588-84a4-f96424a7d82d/NET35_Namespaces_Poster_LORES.pdf

Comment: @Daniel - both posted 3 mins ago??

Answer (score 0):

I found this one for .NET 2.0

http://blogs.msdn.com/photos/brada/images/524537/original.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I tried posters but then i found out that MSDN is more use-full, since: I was looking for a way to know all the hierarchy of the type quickly.